# DJI Mini 2 Mapping Capabilities

Tags: dji, dji-mini-2

I planned to buy my first drone to ease my work. Recently, I found the DJI Mini 2, which I can afford to buy. I've already done some research about drone mapping. Based on my findings on the internet, I could use this technique since it does not require me to install some APK on an android phone. The link is below:

[DJI mini mapping tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d07YUhuXr4s&t=1140s)

So, I want to use this technique for my first drone. My question is, can I do this with DJI Mini 2?

Thanks

Comment: This *should* work, as it looks like that software uses GPS EXIF data to organise the images and DJI aircraft include this data; but it is difficult to be 100% sure without sample images and testing. (I've previously generated orthophotos using [Open Drone Map](https://www.opendronemap.org/) with DJI drones, which works on the above technique, and the results are quite good for consumer grade equipment!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two parts to mapping with a Mini 2.

1. Autopilot App - No autopilot apps will work with the Mini 2 until DJI releases the SDK. Expect [Dronelink](https://www.dronelink.com/) to provide support for the Mini 2 quickly after DJI introduces the SDK.
2. You'll need a photogrammetry processing software.

Here's two posts I've written examining what maps and accuracy you can expect with the original Mini.  The mini 2 should be similar.

- [Can I Map and Survey with the Mavic Mini](https://civiltracker.xyz/map-and-survey-with-the-mavic-mini/)
- [How Accurate is Mapping with the DJI Mavic Mini](https://civiltracker.xyz/how-accurate-is-mapping-with-the-dji-mavic-mini/)

Full Disclosure I'm the founder of Civil Tracker.