# How to use DJI Mini2 to do 3D Photogrammetry?

Tags: dji, photography, dji-mini-2

I have only DJI Mini2. I plan to do 3D mapping (photogrammetry) with mini2.
Dronelink doesn't fit mini2 yet, so how do I use DJI Mini2 to do 3D Mapping?

> Simply put, [Drone Mapping](https://www.dronetechplanet.com/what-is-drone-mapping/) is when you specify the area that you
> like to map and the drone flies around that area and makes a 3D map
> out of it, and this technique is called Photogrammetry.

Comment: Do you mean geographically mapping or surface mapping like photogrammetry?

Comment: @DronesandWhatnot,I mean photogrammetry.

Comment: I believe your question has already been answered in this [previous question](https://drones.stackexchange.com/q/1730)

Comment: DJI has not provided any SDK support for the Mini 2. Until they do, no autopilot not even Dronelink will be able to work with the Mini 2. With the first version of the Mini it took several months for the SDK to be released. I will not buy any DJI.

Comment: Capture lots of images with lots of overlap.  Capture images from all angles.  Capture images on days with flat light and low winds.  Pix4D, DroneDeploy, and Agisoft all have free trials of their software for processing data.  WebODM is freeware but some computer skill are needed for the installation.

Answer (score 1):

By searching YouTube for "DJI mini photogrammetry" you will find some useful tutorial videos. For example, try this one (which teaches how to do photogrammetry with manual controls, without using autopilot features) and turn on CC for English subtitles:

https://youtu.be/4Jr9dH7Pasg